# Turn off UIScrollView indicator scrubbing in iOS 13

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios13

I have a somewhat custom `UIScrollView`, and the new way in iOS 13, where you can scroll the scroll view from the scroll indicator, breaks my designed flow. I do not want to simply hide it.
Is there any way to disable it? I found nothing related to this in the official documentations.

Answer (score 0):

in inspector go to **how the size inspector** and then close the **content layout behaviour** may be it will help you.

Comment: It's turned off, but it has no effect on the said issue

Comment: then close the ""show horizontal and vertical indictor""